# Update LastWriteTime none recursive with PowerShel

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

We are trying to set a modified date on our fileshares:

```
$fileDate = Get-Item $localDir
$fileDate.LastWriteTime = $modifiedDate
```

The problem is when we set one date on a folder, and then add, or modify a date on a sub folder it overrides the date we just added. Is there anyway to set LastWriteTime without affecting other modified dates in the structure?

Comment: Whenever you create something new or set a new `LastWriteTime` to an object inside a folder, the LastWriteTime of that parent folder is automatically also adjusted, since something new happened there. Makes sense to me..

Comment: *This ought to be in a comment. No enough reps* > "add, or modify a date on a sub folder it overrides the date we just added".
> This is the implied behavior on any OS. Add a file/sub-folder to a folder, and the folder's LastWriteTime get's modified.
Workaround: Capture the date you want to set in an variable/hash or even a text file.
Listen for events that add files, subfolders to this folder & reset the modified time again with the variable holding the desired $modifiedDate.